# Piping data from a python script into a .csv or .txt file

Tags: python, shell, csv, pipe, raspberry-pi3

I want to monitor air quality inside my flat (downstairs neighbor is an avid smoker). For so doing, I have a Raspberry Pie 3 Model B+ connected with an Enviro+.

While in the terminal I can run the script that measures small particles.
`python particulates.py` cf. 
https://github.com/pimoroni/enviroplus-python/blob/master/examples/particulates.py

It then runs and display the data in the terminal, like in the picture below: (yes, I am better at lego-ing, than coding). [image: Text]

I am interested in keeping a record of the data in a text files or a csv, so I was thinking if there is a way to pipe the data that is shown on the screen directly into a csv or txt files. I know, I could probably write a simple Python script that makes it nice and tight, but I heard many praises of pipping in Linux, that I wanted to give it a try. Moreover, I saw in one forum that:

> **Awk** and **Sed** are your Shell script friends.
>   In Linux everything is a file, Awk and Sed can write/edit files.
>   Horrible old stuff that comes with every Linux OS and just works.
>
> If you use a webserver then no need for all that x11 desktop bloat stuff, just a headless Linux OS.
>   Easy fit all this on a 128MB card.
>   Busybox has a webserver or you can pick from a bunch of options.
>   I use shell script and Awk/Sed to rewrite the CGI/HTML files on the fly.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248733

I have typed the following in the terminal:

```
python Particulates.py > data.csv
```

I also tried:

```
python Particulates.py | data.csv
```

The data were displayed on the screen, a csv file was created, but the data.csv was empty for both options. If my understanding is correct, I need to put the stdout of the particulates.py into the data.csv. There ought to be something missing in there, because, what I get is far from what this awk/sed advocate was advertising in the forum.

Any clue how I could get this done? and if I were to plot the results shall I use gnuplot ? can I use it in the same line, like in a chain of pipe?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you put your code in the question rather than just a link?

Comment: Sounds like you're writing to standard error or something? Yeah, needs actual code in a [mcve].

Comment: This allows you to log to a file and see the data in your terminal as well: `python Particulates.py 2>&1 | tee -a data.csv`

Comment: Did you set your buffering mode correctly?

Comment: You can save it as a csv file within the script rather than piping it to command line. For that you can use `csv` module or `pandas`

Comment: re code: It is not my code but a script from the example library on the github. If I include it in there, stackoverlflow, tell me that there is mostly code.

re: buffering mode: I am assuming not, as I do not know what this is.

Answer (score 1):

Check the library code [https://github.com/pimoroni/pms5003-python/blob/master/library/pms5003/**init**.py#L66](https://github.com/pimoroni/pms5003-python/blob/master/library/pms5003/__init__.py#L66) to understand which values goes in each columns:

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return """
PM1.0 ug/m3 (ultrafine particles):                             {}
PM2.5 ug/m3 (combustion particles, organic compounds, metals): {}
PM10 ug/m3  (dust, pollen, mould spores):                      {}
PM1.0 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       {}
PM2.5 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       {}
PM10 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                        {}
>0.3um in 0.1L air:                                            {}
>0.5um in 0.1L air:                                            {}
>1.0um in 0.1L air:                                            {}
>2.5um in 0.1L air:                                            {}
>5.0um in 0.1L air:                                            {}
>10um in 0.1L air:                                             {}
""".format(*self.data[:-2], checksum=self.checksum)
```

and use this data to write CSV:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime


pms5003 = PMS5003()
time.sleep(1.0)

try:
    while True:
        try:
            with open('pms5003.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                data = pms5003.read()  # PMS5003Data instance
                dt = datetime.now()
                writer.writerow([dt.isoformat()] + list(data.data[:-2]))
        except ReadTimeoutError:
            pms5003 = PMS5003()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually more what I need. However, if I want to start with the time at which the data are collected, how do I make this happen? I have been trying to do that for at least 2 hours, and well. It's not working. I cannot figure out what displays the time in the initial particulates.py files and why it cannot be put in the writerow.

Comment: In that file data logs via Python logging and where you can see `%(asctime)` formatting param which is log time. I added datetime to answer as first column in ISO format.

Comment: Mhh, thank you.  

Unfortunately, there is an Typerror, at this row  `writer.writerow([dt.isoformat()] + + data.data[:-2])`, saying that it can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list. TO my understanding [brackets] are for list, so I don't see where the problem lies. :/

Comment: Ah, I see, need a minimal edit with `list()` to be type compatible.

Comment: You are really a magician! Thank you!
`logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` Could I also use this p art of the code from the particulates.py file, maybe typing the "datefmt" to have it shown instead of dt.isoformat? I was actually wondering what in the particulates.py call the date and time in front of each pile of records of small particles 
I am just trying to understand better what is going on. In any case, I have the data recording now. :)

Comment: Also, when I call the programm in the terminal, I get the following error:
`File "SMOKE.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open('pms5003.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Omit the newline, it's not implemented in your Python version probably. You've to set any format you like with strftime: `dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thanks. I thought about also monitoring gas data.
[https://github.com/pimoroni/enviroplus-python/blob/master/library/enviroplus/gas.py] I think it will be better to have it in a different csv file (although the same csv would also work) . I modified the code, but keep getting errors.
`with open('n.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
readings1 = pms5003.read() 
readings2 = gas.read_all() #gas data instance
writer.writerow([dt.isoformat()] + list(readings1.data[:-2]) + list(readings2.data[])`

Comment: `list(readings2.data[])` should be `[readings2.oxidising, readings2.reducing, readings2.nh3, readings2.adc]`. It's sad, such a bad design, the different formats in the same data readings interfaces (

Comment: Ok, so I finally had time to get back to it, and with the suggestion, I did not make it to work.
I receive the following errors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/SMOKE/SMOKE-2.py", line 23, in <module>
    readings2 = gas.read_all()
NameError: name 'gas' is not defined

Comment: Did you `import gas`?

Comment: I did.
The code I used is here: 
https://github.com/swiss-JF/SMOKEnGAS/blob/main/SMOKEnGAS.py It includes the above.
It gives the following error
'''%Run SMOKEnGAS.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/SMOKEnGAS/SMOKEnGAS.py", line 27
    writer.writerow([dt.isoformat()] + list(readings1.data[:-2] + [readings2.oxidising, readings2.reducing, readings2.nh3, readings2.adc])
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'''

I tried to rearrange stuff and modify the indent, but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if it's a thing here, but if you have Patreon, or something similar. You deserve some coffee and more! I am in a terrible personal situation due the lack of respect of others of my smoking neighbor, i.e. mental and physical health started to get impacted. In normal time, I would not have to try to work with those things that I obviously do not manage to get it right (I haven't asked questions about the analysis of the data with '''panda''', but it is hard work), so I do not know how to express you my gratitude for the suggestions you provided already. Thanks a lot!